# How to create an XML of this structure

Tags: c#, xelement

I'd like to create an xml structure like below:

```
<root>
    <element name= "text here 1">
        <child>asd</child>
        <child>asd</child>
    </element>
    <element name= "text here 2">
        <child>asd</child>
        <child>asd</child>
    </element>
</root>
```

I'm familiar with

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(mainDirectory);
XElement newElem = new XElement("element", new XElement(child, ""), new XElement(child, ""));
doc.Add(newElem);
doc.Save(mainDirectory);
```

So I think this falls down on how to add the "attribute" when I am creating "element"

Comment: invalid XML you cannot make element = "text here 2"..

Comment: thanks guys! fixed structure, forgot about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an attribute like this

```
new XElement("element",new XAttribute("attribute","value") ,
             new XElement(child, ""), 
             new XElement(child, ""));
```

This would become

```
<element attribute="value">
    <child/>
    <child/>
</element>
```

---

`XElement` is similar to

`public XElement(XName name,params object[] content)`

- due to `params` you can specify any number of objects
- due to `object` you can specify

->`XAttribute`(which gets added to that particular node),

->`string`(which gets wrapped in XText and gets added to node),

->`IEnumerable`,

->`Any other object` is converted to `string` using `ToString()` which is then converted to `XText` and then gets added to the `node`

->if `object` is `null` it is ignored

->if it is `XNode`,gets added to the `node`